# Develop $(\frac{2}{x}-x)^8$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$(\frac{2}{x}-x)^8$

How do I develop this?

My book gives me four options to what that one of the terms of the expression is supposed to look like after the expression is developed. The right option is:$$^8C_3*(\frac{2}{x})^3*(-x)^5$$

I even tried graphing both expressions on my graphical calculator and the graphs are different. Could this be a mistake from my book? If not, how do I solve this?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $(a+b)^8$?  Do that.  After having done that, replace $a$ by $\frac{2}{x}$ and replace $b$ by $-x$.  Then, recognize that some cancellations can occur and pieces can be combined

Comment: Was that the *full* question? The complete binomial power will not expand to a single term.

Comment: @dxiv Yep, that was the full question

Comment: The `right option` you posted is definitely not the correct answer. Just try $x=1$ for example.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok I'll try that

Comment: @dxiv I just posted what the book said was the right option... i don't really know yet. And yeah, like I said the graphs don't even look the same. It's weird

Comment: An answer of $\binom{8}{3}(\frac{2}{x})^3(-x)^5$ **is the $x^2$ term** in the expansion of $(\frac{2}{x}-x)^8$, but not the full expansion

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah... that makes more sense. I admit the phrasing of the question confused me a bit

Comment: And so, if you go back and read the question again, reading **every** word in the question, does that change your answer to dxiv?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah

Comment: What does "develop" mean here?

Comment: @GFauxPas It means simplify, divide into simpler terms. In this case, you have to use Newton's binom formula

Answer (score 1):

The function is:
$$ f(x) = \left( \frac{2}{x} - x \right)^8 = \frac{(2-x^2)^8}{x^8} = x^8 \, \left(\frac{2}{x^2} - 1 \right)^8. $$
These have the expansions:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{8} \binom{8}{k} \, \left(- \frac{2}{x}\right)^{8-k} \, (-x)^k \\
&= \frac{1}{x^8} \, \sum_{k=0}^{8} \binom{8}{k} \, 2^{8-k} \, (-1)^k \, x^{2k}
\end{align}
other expansions follow in a similar manor.